# Bootstrap button focus outline not visible in Safari

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am on Mac 12.5.1 Safari 15.6. I am using Bootstrap 5, and it looks like in Safari buttons can't receive focus. See this custom focus ring example. Is there a trick to get it work? (My code is similar to this example and it works in Chrome and FF.)

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/helpers/focus-ring/#example

[image: Ring visible in Chrome but not in Safari]

Comment: How do you try to set focus? What version of mac os? What version of Safari?

Comment: I am just saying this bootstrap example doesn't work in Safari. The focus is triggered by user clicking on the button. Focus ring is not visible as it should be.

Comment: Does the _official_ example show focus outline in your browser?

Comment: @MrUpsidown Simply clicking on the buttons sets focus on them. The outline isn't set, so this works but not the box-shadow

Comment: The`<a>` tag doesn't seem to get the `:focus` pseudo-class applied when clicked on Safari. It works when using tab key to navigate to the button (if and only if you have enabled keyboard navigation in mac os settings) and only if you use a `<button>` instead of an `<a>`. You should search the [issue list](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues) and report this if it's not there already.